# Eclipse Autocomplete for top level object?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

I have a "Pear" object that inherits from "Fruit"

When I press (autocomplete) <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> I get all the members etc for both Fruit and Pear.

Is there a key stroke for just showing me the "Pear" members?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no filtering of that kind.
The only advanced filtering available right now is [proposed by Mylyn](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn_FAQ#Content_assist_troubleshooting) and based on its notion of [Task](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn_User_Guide#Task_List).

[image]

But it won't filter out the super class member functions.